# Is the license still applies for the autogenerated java files from the jaxb based out of xml schema?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Each generated java file has this header comments

```
// This file was generated by the JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, v2.2.8-b130911.1802 
// See <a href="http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb">http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb</a> 
// Any modifications to this file will be lost upon recompilation of the source schema.
```

I am wondering the license of jaxb applies to my generated files?

Comment: Questions about licensing are [off-topic](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing). Ask on the [Open Source StackExchange](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: It has been asked there http://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/4478/is-the-license-still-applies-for-the-autogenerated-java-class-files-generated-fr